# mySQL updating all fields of a table from another

Tags: mysql

I have table A and table B. Both of them have the same fields.   If Table B has new data, I would like do complete update on Table A from Table B. It's complete replacement. or clone the data from Table B to table A

So, I have the sql as followed.

```
sql="update `table A` select * from `table B`"
```

I executed that but it didn't give me the right result.

what should be the right sql?

Comment: How do you match records in `table A` to their corresponding records in `table B`?

Comment: First: what does it mean "has new date" exactly. Second: do you mean to completly replace the table data? So remove all thata from A and copy all the data from B?

Comment: yes, complete replacement of data from Table B.  It's new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a copy of table B, you can do this with

```
CREATE TABLE A SELECT * FROM B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TRUNCATE `table A`;
INSERT INTO `table A` SELECT * FROM `table B`;
```